# proof for $\sum_{r=0}^{40} {40 \choose r} (-1)^r {100-r \choose 40} = 1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

$\sum_{r=0}^{40} {40 \choose r} (-1)^r {100-r \choose 40} = 1$

I have tried expanding, simplifying it. It doesn't work. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are you sure your equation is correct ? I don't think $\sum_{r=0}^{40} {40 \choose r} (-1)^r {100-r \choose 40} $ should be equal to $1$. Could you please using your computer to evaluate the left-hand side of the equation to see whether your equation is right ?